# Task WaitAll not working properly in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, task, wait

I am using System.Threading.Tasks

Here is sample code ::

**Case 1::**

```
            List<string> testTerms = new List<string>();
            testTerms.Add("test1");
            testTerms.Add("test2");

            List<Task> lstTask = new List<Task>();

            foreach (string tTerm in testTerms)
            {
                Task<List<string>> task1 =
                Task<List<string>>.Factory.StartNew(() => SearchString());
                lstTask.Add(task1);
            }

            Task[] searchTasks = (Task[])lstTask.ToArray();
            Task.WaitAll(searchTasks.ToArray(), 1000);


        public List<string> SearchString()
        {
            .....
            Thread.Sleep(20000);
            return list;
        }
```

Now in this , It should wait for 1000 miliseconds for all task to complete.
But I have provided `Thread.Sleep(20000);` in `SearchString()`
So what happens is, It will wait for 20 seconds here even if I have provided `Task.WaitAll(searchTasks.ToArray(), 1000);`
**[This is not expected]**

Now consider another scenario.

**Case 2**

```
Task[] tasks = new Task[0]
         {
          Task.Factory.StartNew(() => SearchString())                                
          };

                     Task.WaitAll(tasks,1000);
```

Now in this case it what happens is , It will wait for only 1000 miliseconds even if I have provided `Thread.Sleep(20000);` in `SearchString()`.
**[This is expected]**

So the **Case 2** is working properly but **Case 1**.

So what is the issue with **Case 1**?

Comment: Can't reproduce.  I took your code and ran it and `WaitAll` only waited for two seconds, as expected.

Comment: Same here, there's something else in your code you haven't reproduced in your example.

Answer (score 2):

I can't reproduce your issue. I think you're mistaking the Wait for a CancellationToken.

My code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<string> testTerms = new List<string>();
    testTerms.Add("test1");
    testTerms.Add("test2");

    List<Task> lstTask = new List<Task>();

    foreach (string tTerm in testTerms)
    {
        Task<List<string>> task1 =
        Task<List<string>>.Factory.StartNew(() => SearchString());
        lstTask.Add(task1);
    }

    Task[] searchTasks = (Task[])lstTask.ToArray();
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + ": Waiting");
    Task.WaitAll(searchTasks.ToArray(), 1000);
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + ": Done Waiting");
    Console.ReadKey();
}

public static List<string> SearchString()
{
    Thread.Sleep(20000);
    return new List<string>();
}
```

The output:

```
6/7/2013 10:05:05 AM: Waiting
6/7/2013 10:05:06 AM: Done Waiting
```

The Task threads will continue to execute but the calling/control thread will not **wait** for it to finish longer than the indicated time. It won't **cancel** the thread however after that time, just continue execution.